# MySql Where Clause with wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

Trying to pick up some Sql and am confused by the following example. Would anyone happen to know why:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CustomerID
From Orders
Inner Join Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate LIKE '%6';
```

Happens to return over 100 entries with an Order Date ending in 1996, while on the other hand:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate, Customers.CustomerID
From Orders
Inner Join Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
WHERE Orders.OrderDate LIKE '%96';
```

returns me 0 entries. I'm using the customers data from w3schools. I'm quite confused why this wouldn't work.

Comment: What datatype is `Orders.OrderDate`?

Comment: Looks to me to be a string: 7/4/1996 for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect OrderDate is a Date or DateTime field. Try this instead:

```
WHERE
YEAR(Orders.OrderDate) = 1996
```

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.

Comment: But this still doesn't answer the question... I'm curious why one query would return results and the other wouldn't.

Comment: @abl LIKE is a string comparison operator, it does not work with dates. OrderDate is a date field - so you need to use date functions. YEAR is a date function that takes a date and returns a year.

Comment: @Donal `LIKE` does work with `DATE` and `DATETIME` fields in (at least some versions of) MySQL, although using it can raise a warning. I'm getting identical results with `dateField LIKE '%96%'` and `DATE_FORMAT(dateField, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '%96%'`